# Alfresco slingshot search numberFound and totalRecords number different

Tags: search, numbers, alfresco

I'm using Alfresco 5.0.d

I see in the search json result (with firebug console panel) that in addition to  result items , 2 other properties are returned :   `numberFound`  and `totalRecords`. It seems that Alfresco search engine considers `numberFound` as total items found.
So it display "numberFound   results founded" to user.

The problem is that `numberFound` is not equals to `totalRecords`.

I see that `totalRecords` is the correct number of search result (in fact search always return `totalRecords` number of items).

So i decided to see in the webscript that performs search (`alfresco-remote-api-5.0.d.jar\alfresco\templates\webscripts\org\alfresco\slingshot\search\search.lib.js`).
We can easly see that the `numberFound` property comes from this statement

```js
var rs = search.queryResultSet(queryDef);
var numberFound  = rs.meta.numberFound ;
```

About `totalRecords` property, it comes from the same statement but a little bit different:

```js
var totalRecords = rs.nodes.length
```

which is the correct value of number of item really found.

So is it an Alfresco api bug?
If no , is it possible that error comes from my query parameters?
Can someone explains me what does mean the `numberFound` property?

Thank you.

Comment: Does that API do paging? If so, you'd expect the total to be different to the amount returned, as you'd only get part of the results in a page

Comment: Hi Gagravarr. The API does pagination. But  i'm sur that it isn't a problem of pagination. In my test scenaries, found item number never higher than  single page size.  And also,  the faceted filter numbers are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the URL of java file which is getting called when you are executing `search.queryResultSet(queryDef)` code.

you can refer below method in the java file.It is adding all the things.

https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/repository/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/jscript/Search.java

```
public Scriptable queryResultSet()  //This is java method which is getting called.
```

Below is the code which is written for what you are getting in result.

```
 meta:
    {
     numberFound: long, // total number found in index, or -1 if not known or not supported by this resultset
     facets: 
     {              // facets are returned for each field as requested in the SearchParameters fieldfacets 
        field: 
        {            // each field contains a map of facet to value
                    facet: value,
        },
     }
    }
```

Comment: Hi 


I canot see the problem. I want  to debug what happen in this java class. 

How can i do that ?